# Programmatically get previous/next animation in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, sendkeys

I am trying to control slide animations from action buttons in PowerPoint VBA. I manage to navigate to next and previous animations in the current slide using `sendKeys`.

The action buttons basically runs `displayPrevious` and `displayNext` macros as follows:

```
Sub displayPrevious()
    SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
End Sub

Sub displayNext(ByRef oShp As Shape)
    SendKeys ("{RIGHT}")
End Sub
```

However, this results in an unwanted feature. After the last animation the next button switch the next or previous slide.

One way I am thinking to do this is maybe, get the next or previous to be executed and if its a change slide just don't run the `sendkeys`.

Or maybe I am thinking this the wrong way and there can be an easier solution?

Comment: PowerPoint VBA object model contain a number of animation objects (such as [AnimationSettings.AnimationOrder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.animationsettings.animationorder). I would be surprised if you really have to play around with sendkeys to control them.

Comment: okay, but have lots of shapes merged for animation. for eg. i have a total of about 60 shapes in the slide but only around 12 clicks for them to appear. At first i wanted to get the click count and match then with the shapes count but this would not work.

Comment: I have done almost nothing with PowerPoint VBA, but I have done enough Excel VBA to know that `SendKeys` is almost never needed. It is an unreliable tool which has some utility in running (from VBA) GUI applications that lack an API, but Office VBA revolves around controlling Office via a fairly elaborate API. The information about what shape appears with what click is likely there somewhere, though perhaps not in a convenient form. But really, I am just guessing. The little that I did with PowerPoint VBA gave me the impression that it is the neglected stepchild of Office VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to find a (working but not perfect) solution.

Basically just checking the current animation being played from `getClickIndex` and comparing to `0` for previous and `getClickCount` for next.

```
Sub displayPrevious()
   If ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GetClickIndex <> 0 Then
        SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
    End If
End Sub

Sub displayNext()
    If ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GetClickIndex <> ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GetClickCount Then
        SendKeys ("{RIGHT}")
    End If
End Sub
```